# @Temporal - DateFormat - JPA

Tags: mysql, spring, jpa, date-formatting, temporal

I am using below in my **Customer** entity to map `Date` field

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "birthdate")
@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy")
private Date birthDate;
```

But still `BirthDate` is saved in `yyyy-MM-dd` format. I have tried setting in setter method for field `birthDate` using DateFormat, but still same response.

Database is Mysql, column is of type `Date`.
I wish to set the value in `dd-MM-yyyy` format.

Comment: DateTimeFormat has nothing to do with JPA. @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE) means that the date is stored and read using a java.sql.Date. The way it's stored in your database depends on the database, and on type of your database column. But a DATE type doesn't have any format. The tool used to visualize the date chooses how to display the date.

Comment: Seems like an XY problem. Why do you need to store date like that?

Comment: @JBNizet I am just thinking is it really required to store it as date when i just want `dd-MM-yyyy` and don't even want to play on this using `Date` functions. Can i simply use `varchar` type.

Comment: No, you really don't want that. You wouldn't even be able to query for a chronologically sorted list. Not to mention the inability to query for rows between two dates, etc. Use the right type. A date is a date. Not a varchar.

Comment: @JBNizet Make sense, so conversion is the only options it seems.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know from former project, this is the given date format in MySQL and can't be changed so straight forward. I would set the date pattern in mapping the same as in databank `(YYYY-MM-DD)` and reformat it later in the usage.