# How to set and save Date object

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am writing a JPA application and I have a Date object that needs to be set and then saved in the database.

Here's an example:

```
 @Embeddable
 public class Semester {

     @Column(name = "is_started",
             columnDefinition = "tinyint(1)",
             nullable = false)
     private Boolean isStarted;

     @Column(name = "is_finished",
             columnDefinition = "tinyint(1)",
             nullable = false)
     private Boolean isFinished;

     @Column(name = "starting_date")
     private Date startingDate;

     @Column(name = "register_deadline_date")
     private Date registerDeadlineDate;
 }
```

I want to know How to Set a Date object to pass to my entity:

Should it be something like:

```
 System.out.println("Enter Year: ");
 String year = new Scanner(System.in).next();
 System.out.println("Enter month: ");
 String month = new Scanner(System.in).next();
 System.out.println("Enter day: ");
 String day = new Scanner(System.in).next();
 
 Date startingDate = new Date(day, month, year);
 Semester semester = new Semester();
 semester.setStartingDate(startingDate);
 repository.save(semester);
```

I did this but this constructor either doesn't work anymore or I am doing something wrong.   Thanks in advance.

Comment: Both `Date` classes are terribly flawed and should be avoided. They were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes. For a date only without time-of-day and without time zone or offset, use `LocalDate`. See [tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Comment: So what do you suggest?

Comment: you should also use @Temporal if you are saving the date object.- https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-date-time

Comment: @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd/mm/yyyy")
    @Column(name = "birth_date"
            , nullable = false)
    private Date birthDate;

I did this instead is it ok? or do I have to add @Temporal too?

Answer (score 1):

I succeeded at that. 
Maybe, cause is that you didn't write @Entity,@Table(name = "foo").

```
@Setter
@Getter
@Table(name = "foo") // your name of Table
@Entity
public class Semester {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "starting_date")
    private Date startingDate;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "id : "+id +",startingDate : "+ startingDate;
    }
}
```

Repository interface

```
@Repository
public interface FooRepo extends JpaRepository<Semester, Long> {

}
```

execute class

```
@Component
public class FooExecute {

    @Autowired
    FooRepo fooRepo;

    @Autowired
    FooRepo repository;

    public void execute() {
         Date startingDate = new Date(121, 8, 29);
         Semester semester = new Semester(); 
         semester.setId(2L);
         semester.setStartingDate(startingDate);
         semester = repository.save(semester);
         System.out.println("result:"+semester.toString());
         //result:id : 2,startingDate : 2021-09-29
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bro That helps a lot! 
But can i use SimpleDateFormat for the Date ?

Comment: You can't use SinpleDateformat. Reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50888699/temporal-dateformat-jpa

Comment: System.out.println("Enter The Register DeadLine Date(dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm): ");
            String dateFormat = ApplicationContext.getStringScanner().next();



java.util.Date registerDeadLine = simpleDateFormat.parse(dateFormat);
                java.sql.Date sqlRegisterDeadLine = new java.sql.Date(registerDeadLine.getTime());
                semester.setRegisterDeadlineDate(sqlRegisterDeadLine);

This is What I did bro. What do you think?

Comment: @RealOg I tried to that. It was sucess. I think it is not bad